# Make a call in Lua, on a potentially not exposed Function in tolua++

Tags: c++, lua, call, tolua++

I have a Lua script that uses some functions of my C++ application. 
I use this script with 2 different C++ application, and I would like to be able to protect a call for not being bound through tolua.

For example:
- Let's say that I have two C++ applications: MyApp1 and MyApp2
- I made a wrapper of MyApp1 with tolua++ and I call one of its functions like this in a Lua script:

```
MyApp1:MyFunc()
```

Now I use this same script with MyApp2, that doesn't have any tolua++ binding of this type.
And I then get an error of this type:

> [string "MyApp2.lua"]:157: attempt to index global 'MyApp1' (a nil value)

So I would like Lua not to send me an error when calling this method.
I tried to use:

```
pcall( MyApp1:MyFunc() )
```

But the script keeps on crashing on this line.

Comment: how about `MyApp1 = MyApp2` in the second application.

Comment: @user1095108 - in this case MyApp2 is also nil, as it doesn't have any tolua++ bindings.

Comment: @W.B.: Yeah, then you need the `if` tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if MyApp1 then 
  MyApp1:MyFunc() 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if MyApp1 then
   MyApp1:MyFunc()
end
```

Above will work, but isn't it cleaner to separate application dependent and independent scripts? That way you woudn't have to worry about it.

Comment: Ah very simple so! Thanx W.B. for your answer:)